# Pop outs using js when clicked on a box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created  a simple website which is going to be a part of a bigger project:
Here is the screen shot:
[image: Website]
And here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popup () {
        var thought = prompt("Please enter your thougt");
    }
</script>
<style>
.fixed-size-square {
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}
.fixed-size-square span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white
}
.size-square {
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}
.size-square span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white
}
.square {
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
}
.square span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white
}
.fixed-size-square, .size-square, .square {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    zoom: 1; 
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*margin: auto;*/
}
button {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px auto;
}
.divn {  
    padding:30px; 
    background:red; 
    width:1px; 
    border-radius:35px; 
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    /*position: absolute;
    margin: auto;*/
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to zen module</h1>
<div class='divn'></div> 
<div class="fixed-size-square" onclick="popup();">
  <span>Past Thoughts</span>
</div>

<div class="size-square" onclick="popup();">
    <span>Present Thoughts</span>
</div>

<div class="square" onclick="popup();">
    <span>Future Thoughts</span>
</div>
<button>I've no thoughts</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to have 2 functions for `window.prompt("question", "default")`. When I click on `Okay` in prompt, then a function should read as `Okay clicked`, and when `cancel` button is clicked, another function should read `cancel clicked`. How can I do it?

Comment: The code has been modified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
    var x = prompt("dvdvbd", "default");
if (x != null) {  //if user click ok 
    //do this
}
else {  //if user click cancel
    //do this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a window.prompt("question", "default")

Here's a demo:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt

Comment: Sorry, the question needs to be edited and you might need to edit your answer

Comment: Then see these other answers.  Window.prompt will return `NULL` on cancel, so check for that.

Answer (score 1):

The prompt box returns `null` if the user hits cancel, and an empty string if he hits `OK` (with nothing entered.)  All you need to do is check if the `prompt()` returns `null`.

```js
if (prompt("Question") != null){
  
  alert("You clicked OK!");
  
  }else {alert("What\'s wrong with you? Click OK!")}
```